# Personalizar Logs en Java (Logger)

Tags: java

Buen día,

Estoy construyendo un log a un programa hecho en java pero me gustaría personalizar mejor la forma en la que se escribe, actualmente tengo esto:

```
INFO:   ==============================INICIO============================
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM com.empresa.www.run.CreaLog escribeLog
INFO:   Inicia lectura xml..
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM com.empresa.www.run.CreaLog escribeLog
INFO:   Xml leido OK!
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM com.empresa.www.run.CreaLog escribeLog
INFO:   Se inicio el proceso XXX periodo 20200131
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM com.empresa.www.run.CreaLog escribeLog
INFO:   Numero de regitros a procesar: 6
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM com.empresa.www.run.CreaLog escribeLog
INFO:   Inicia proceso fila: 1
ene 14, 2020 9:02:17 AM com.empresa.www.run.CreaLog escribeLog
INFO:   No encontro terminos y condiciones para el cliente: 00000000 con fecha: 20191022
ene 14, 2020 9:02:17 AM com.empresa.www.run.CreaLog escribeLog
INFO:   Inicia proceso fila: 2
ene 14, 2020 9:02:17 AM com.empresa.www.run.CreaLog escribeLog
SEVERE:     Error en la lectura de la fila journal
1
```

Y me gustaría algo como esto, eliminar el nombre de la clase y los saltos de línea

```
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM INFO:   ==============================INICIO============================
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM INFO:   Inicia lectura xml..
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM INFO:   Xml leido OK!
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM INFO:   Se inicio el proceso XXX periodo 20200131
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM INFO:   Numero de regitros a procesar: 6
ene 14, 2020 9:02:16 AM INFO:   Inicia proceso fila: 1
ene 14, 2020 9:02:17 AM INFO:   No encontro terminos y condiciones para el cliente: 00000000000 con fecha: 20191022
ene 14, 2020 9:02:17 AM INFO:   Inicia proceso fila: 2
ene 14, 2020 9:02:17 AM SEVERE:     Error en la lectura de la fila joUrnal
```

Comment: Esto es lo que necesitas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194765/how-do-i-get-java-logging-output-to-appear-on-a-single-line

Answer (score 0):

Hola si les interesa finalmente encontré lo que quería en este sitio: (https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/logging/customizing-default-format.html)